# C# Datetime value changing when coming into Service Stack api method

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, servicestack

We are using ServiceStack for our web services but we have noticed than any DateTime object in the request DTO is being changed. The hours are changing based upon what the server's timezone offset is. So say I'm sending in a request from Eastern Time to a server that is hosting the ServiceStack api in a Mountain Time zone it is changing the date down two hours once our api method gets the request.

I've been trying to find how to modify the deserialization of the datetime value with ServiceStack to prevent this from happening and have not found any elegant solution yet. I thought that by making `ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;`
That this would treat any datetime value coming into the server as UTC and not convert to the datetime with a Kind of Local. It doesn't seem to make a difference on dates coming in.

I have tried using `ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn` to change the string to a datetime but doing so requires stripping out all info except for datetime tick information.

Am I missing something obvious with this? Seems like there should be an easier way to prevent this behavior.

Comment: What do the values look like over the wire?  I assume they are in ISO601 format, but do they have a trailing Z or an offset?  An example value would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely want to use this instead:

```
JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
```

Comment: This is helpful and I will need to remember this for later use because I want to switch to start using UTC throughout our code but in the meantime I have to stick with how it is sending without UTC. I did make the change and now keeps the actual time but in UTC format. I was wondering if there was any way to keep the datetime with the value from what it was sent as without converting it to UTC. Mainly because the datetime values are used for filtering based upon dates to return result sets and the dates stored in the database are not UTC.

Comment: @user1568610 Nope, it's always serialized to UTC on the wire by design and will by default deserialize it into a local time, but can be kept as UTC with the above config option.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help and information. I'll just stick with the custom deserialization until I can get code updated to use UTC.